# Battery not showing up 18.04 LTS

Tags: 18.04, battery

I recently dual booted my Acer Espire E5-573G using Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04. Upon booting up I saw that there was no battery icon. When I did `upower-d`its shows 
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0Hc3.png).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the fix, needed to update my BIOS to the lastest version.

Comment: The BIOS updates on the Acer site are only for Windows. Where did you get the BIOS update from?

Comment: @bflemi3 I was dual booting so I had Windows 10 on the machine as well.So I ran the BIOS updater on that.